# MKAnnotation with error margin

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm using a `MKMapView` and use annotations with custom `MKAnnotationView`s in order to display other person's locations. Although, as the location of other people have error margins, I would like to represent the error margin just like the blue circle around your current location. I looked in the documentation of `MKAnnotation` and `MKMapViewDelegate` but couldn't find anything related. Is it possible to achieve this? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it wasn't actually possible. Although, I could draw the accuracy circle myself, by using an `MKCircle` with the accuracy radius and implementing `mapView:rendererForOverlay:` on the `MKMapView`'s delegate.